# Making location scroll buttons on the side of a webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious how to make a webpage with buttons on the side, that scroll to different locations (smoothly, not that jump right to the location).

Here is an example: http://creativefreedomguide.com/

I see from the source code that it uses [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for the menu.  Does Bootstrap have functions for supporting this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: For Jquery , refer  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly easy.

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Ne9B/
including the jquery from the css-tricks that fizzbuzz included above.

```
 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

pedalpete beat me to it, but since i did the work, i'll share a very slightly different example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franvarn/9fcVd/1/)

the only real difference is that i included a back to top option

```
<a name="top">link/div/something to go back to</a>
```

then

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

Comment: Well, actually Fran, your version doesn't have the menu as statically floating, but you did a much nicer job with the blue discs.

Comment: right! but that's why i included the 'back to top'! :)